# Kernel functions for vectors in discrete spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, machine-learning

There are lots of choices for kernel functions $k(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y})$ in continuous spaces (e.g., $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^d$), such as the RBF kernel, etc.
However, what are some common kernel functions for vectors on discrete spaces (e.g., $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \in\{0,1\}^d$, or even $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \in\{1,\dots,K\}^d$)?

Comment: Just restrict any continuous kernel you know.

Comment: Could you please elaborate some more in an answer? For example, how would one go about restricting an RBF kernel to $\{0,1\}^d$?

Comment: Just evaluate it on the elements of $\{ 0, 1 \}^d$ as if they were elements of $\mathbb{R}^d$. In general, if $K(y_1, y_2) : Y \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is any kernel on any set $Y$ and $f : X \to Y$ is any function, then $K(f(x_1), f(x_2)) : X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a kernel on $X$. (I'm not claiming this will give a kernel that is useful for anything; for that question better to ask at stats.SE rather than here.)

Comment: Oh, I see. You are correct of course, although I was more looking for discrete kernels that are commonly used in practice. I will try stats.SE. Thanks!